# Shopping Cart Price Rule where the discount given changes according to the shopping cart total

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, promotions

Is there any way in Magento 1.9.x to set up a shopping cart rule that does the following:

Shopping Cart Total > £1000
Discount = 5%

Shopping Cart Total <= £1000
Discount = 10%

This way we can give out the same voucher code to lots of clients, and give them a discount that doesn't get too big when the shopping cart total is over a thousand pounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would require creating two Shopping Cart Price Rules.

To have the discount levels start from specific subtotal we need to split the promotion into two separate promotions where second is disabling further rules proceeding OR both have constant start and end levels and are configured at the same priority (second approach is easier and I'll describe it but if you have more promotions that could be combined then the way with Stop Further Rules Processing could be the only one to make them work as expected).

Enough theory, let's create it.

## First Rule **Subtotal <= 1000 Pounds -10% discount**

1. Login to your admin panel.
2. Go into Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules
3. Create new rule: **Subtotal <= 1000 Pounds then give 10% discounts**
4. Give the Rule some name and configure the generals. 
   **Remember that LOWER Priority = Takes precedence.**
5. Now select tab "Conditions" on the left side of your screen.

   Leave the configuration as it is:

   [*If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :*]
   **Subtotal** *equals or lower than* 1000.0000
6. Now select "Actions" on left menu. 
   Apply: Percent of product price discount. 
   Discount Amount: 10

## Second Rule

**Subtotal > 1000 Pounds then give 5% discounts**

1. Give the Rule some name and configure the generals.
2. Select tab "Conditions" on the left side of your screen. 
   Leave the basic configuration as it is:
   Condition:
   [*If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :*]
   **Subtotal** *greater than* 1000.0000
3. Now select "Actions" on left menu. 
   Apply: Percent of product price discount. 
   Discount Amount: 5